# How set custom .env in jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

Hello I am trying to write UT for following function :

```
function checkEnvirenmentHost() {
  var hostDetails
  if (process.env.HTTPS_HOST) {
    hostDetails = process.env.HTTPS_HOST;
  } else if (process.env.https_HOST) {
    hostDetails = process.env.https_HOST;
  } else if (process.env.HTTP_HOST) {
    hostDetails = process.env.HTTP_HOST;
  } else if (process.env.http_HOST) {
    hostDetails = process.env.http_HOST;
  } else {
    hostDetails = false;
  }
  return hostDetails
}
```

the issue is if I run UT in different environment the UT will fail because the environment variable might not be present, so is there a way to upload a custom .env file while running Unit test in jasmine. I read about this feature is available in 'jtest' but I cant find the same for jasmine. Can someone pls suggest a way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to load environment variables from `.env` file. You can set the environment variable in each test case to test each code branch.

E.g.(*"jasmine": "^3.6.3"*)

`index.test.js`:

```js
const checkEnvirenmentHost = require('./');

describe('72563579', () => {
  it('should pass - HTTPS_HOST', () => {
    process.env.HTTPS_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    const actual = checkEnvirenmentHost();
    expect(actual).toEqual('127.0.0.1');
    process.env.HTTPS_HOST = undefined;
  });
  it('should pass - https_HOST', () => {
    process.env.https_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    const actual = checkEnvirenmentHost();
    expect(actual).toEqual('127.0.0.1');
    process.env.https_HOST = undefined;
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
Executing 2 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 37424)

Test Suites & Specs:

1. 72563579
   ✔ should pass - https_HOST (5ms)
   ✔ should pass - HTTPS_HOST (1ms)


2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.022 seconds
Randomized with seed 37424 (jasmine --random=true --seed=37424)


>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   2 of 2
Expects: 2 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.021 seconds
```